# How can I import a wallet from aleth zero into geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, alethzero

I have a wallet file from the old alert zero implementation. How can I import it into my geth client?

Answer (score 1):

From [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/49ilr0/how_to_export_account_from_alethzero_to_mist/) :

under Accounts,"Export selected key". Copy that key into a text file and take note of the location (I saved mine as /home/.ethereum/keyfile.prv). To import it you need to use command line tools. For instance I have geth, so `geth account import <location of the text file with key>.`